# Event listeners not applied to content loaded with jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building a single page application through Wordpress and I noticed that click functions, etc, are not triggered on content I load in with AJAX.

For example, let's say I have an alert that fires whenever a link is clicked. That alert won't fire on content that's been loaded via AJAX... I think it's because no event listeners get attached to that new content.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Bind/rebind the events to the new items on the completion of a successful AJAX call.

Comment: attach event listeners to the new content.

Comment: The best way is to delegate click event: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Post some code so others understand your problem well.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I think the answer might be to use jQuery delegate on the container content is loaded into: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_delegate.asp

Is this a good approach? Are there any drawbacks?

Comment: could be, depends on your situation. I certainly wouldn't use `document` as a target though, and i'd suggest never using w3schools as a reference or place to learn things.

Comment: I switched to .on(), and my functions worked fine. I didn't know that .on() worked for elements added to the DOM dynamically. What's not good about W3 in your opinion?

Comment: It often presents poor practices as "best" practices, doesn't note the dangers of some vulnerable methods in the reference, and in general is just a poor resource. Use official docs instead, such as the MDN for javascript/dom/css or jquery.com for jquery. These are all maintained by the community so you can be sure that they're using the most up to date practices.